# What is an extension error?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, intersection

I am getting an extension error when I try and intersect some points and polygons.

[image]

Here is a photo of what I am trying to intersect:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using geographic coordinates or a projection? If there are no other obvious problems (and based on comments it sounds like there are not), I would try using a projection.

Comment: Is "extension error" a typo?  If so, could be worth correcting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is said there that your points and polygons don't intersect at all and thus you have "empty output".

You can check intersection visually by loading both layers - do you see any point inside polygons? Also check your intersection settings when running Intersect tool.

Comment: Here is a photo of what I am trying to intersect.  The coordinate systems are the same.  I add an excel sheet then click on display XY data and select the same coordinate system as the polygons.  Everything looks exactly like it's supposed to.  Not sure what I am doing incorrectly. 

http://i.imgur.com/BYJ1w.png

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to save XY data (points) to external feature class (shp, GDB) ? and then use it the Intersect tool.

Comment: Yuppers.  That's how I am able to keep the table attributes.  When I save as a shp file.  Here are two more photos when I try to investigate the intersection error.  I have no idea what they mean.
http://i.imgur.com/fSUfA.png
http://i.imgur.com/D8VkC.png

Comment: Have you set any Environment Variables before executing Intersect tool? What coordinate system is used for your data?

Comment: I have not set any variables.  I tried setting the XY variables to decimal degrees which is what they are for both the polygons and points.  But it made no difference.

Comment: These are the coordinate systems for both:
Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:  Greenwich
Angular Unit:  Degree

Comment: Oh and I should note that I have successfully performed this already using the same polygons and a different data set.

Comment: In this case I can recommend you to try converting your point feature class to different format (shp/PGDB/FGDB). Try to copy both points and polygons to one common GDB.